Enable or disable datagrid cell value
I have a datagrid please note its data grid not data grid view.
And this datagrid have
Column A  with some String values
And
Column B
With      Datagridboolcolum(checkbook type)
What I need to achieve is disable or enable the checkbook of Column B based on some conditions
In datagridview its little easy but how will we implement it in datagrid?
My datagrid is populated using datasource

There is a DataGrid control in WinForms but it has basically been obsolete since 2005 and doesn't exist in .NET Core, including .NET 5 and later. Are you really using this control?

@jmcilhinney we are using legacy and we still using datagrid. That's the issue

No code provided. These questions almost always get closed.

I don't remember much about DataGrid except that DataGridView is better. You may as well update to the "newer" control. If not now... when?

Thank u guys i got the answer what I was looking for.

I resolved the issue in the following way.
I added one event CurrentCellChanged like below
Private Sub dgMyGrid_currentCellChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as eventArgs) handles dgMygrid.currentcellchanged
Dim rowNum As Integer=dgmygrid.currentcell.rownumber
Dim column As Integer  = dgmygrid.currentcell.columnnumber
Dim dgselectedcolum As datagridcolumnstyle = dgmygrid.tablestyles(mytablename).gridcolumnstyles(colnum)


If dgMygrid.mappimgname.equals(mycolumnname) andalso dgmygrid.beginedit()

Dim dataview As dataview =ctype(dgmygrid.datasource,dataview)

If mycondition
    Dgselectedcolumn.readonly=true
Else
    Dgselectedcolum.readonly =false

Dgmygrid.endedit(dgselectedcolumn, rownum, false)

